# Grease Pencil minimum thickness

Tags: grease-pencil, scale

I am trying to turn down the size of some GP strokes to taper them. Ideally, i'd like to reduce the size of the last point in the stroke to 0 and have a sharp tip, much like you get on a curve when scaling the radius to 0. However, it seems that I can't go below this line thickness:

[image]

I've tried adjusting the thickness with alt+S, in sculpt mode, with a modifier, and with Stroke Thickness in Adjustments. None can make it thinner than this. Is there any other way to reduce it, or to get a sharp tip on a stroke? Why is there this arbitrary minimum? I'm working at usual scale of 1BU = 1 meter. This is my character's neck, and this isn't thin enough for close-up shots.

I've also tried scaling the GP object, but this same minimum size still exists. I suppose I could scale the character up by x10, but then that creates problems with some physics and dynamics that expect 1 unit to = 1 meter.